# What is the `!` operator used for in MikroORM Typescript objects?

Tags: typescript, mikro-orm

What's the syntax for having an `!` before the colon in a key declaration for JS objects?

MikroORM syntax for class

```
@Entity()
export class Post {
  // the @PrimaryKey invokes a function that takes the returned key/value pair and adds it as a column / information
  @PrimaryKey()
  id!: number;

  @Property({ type: "date", default: "NOW()" })
  createdAt = new Date();

  @Property({ type: "date", default: "NOW()", onUpdate: () => new Date() })
  updatedAt = new Date();

  @Property({ type: "text" })
  title!: string;
}
```

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you provided a code example to give us context.

Comment: Never seen that. How about a real example? `!` in JavaScript *(and many other languages)* is the boolean `not` operator.

Comment: From your description, it would appear to be [a syntax error](https://jsbin.com/kilovamoho/1/edit?js,console).

Comment: It would help if you could post a bigger code sample so we could see it in context. But if I had to guess, you're dealing with TypeScript (rather than just JavaScript), and the exclamation mark is the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-), which tells the TypeScript compiler that the property has a value (in cases where the compiler cannot infer that itself - for example, when using `Object.assign` in the constructor).

Comment: `{
 key!: "val"
}` throws a syntax error in the js console

Comment: As I understand the question (given I think have the same question), you're asking if Mikro-ORM's ts-morph feature uses ?: and !: to imply anything about the Entity beyond their regular meanings in TypeScript.

And I'm sad to say, none of the answers specifically address this. Looking into it myself now. Will post a response if I find anything.

Answer (score 4):

In *JavaScript*, it's a syntax error, but the code you've shown is [*TypeScript*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) code. TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript that adds type information. In TypeScript, `text!: string` is a type definition saying:

- There is a thing called called `text` (in this context I'd expect it to be a variable, not an object property).
- Its type is `string`.
- It's [definitely assigned](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) even if it's not obvious from the context that that's true.

Edit: Now that you've shown the full `class` definition, here's what it says that the `Post` class has:

- An `id` property of type `number`, that is definitely assigned/initialized even though the code in the `class` construct doesn't show an initialization.
- A `createdAt` property initialized with `new Date()` (which will make TypeScript infer that its type is `Date`)
- An `updatedAt` property also initialized with `new Date()`
- A `title` property whose type is `string` that, like `id`, is definitely initialized even though that initialization isn't shown in the `class` code.
- It uses various decorators related to your ORM, such as `@PrimaryKey`, that connect those properties to the model and say what the ORM should do with them.

Those definite assignment/initialization assertions aren't uncommon in class code that uses an ORM.

Answer (score 1):

The bang operator `!` is Typescript's [definite assignment assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html).

It's a way to tell the compiler to "ignore that this variable is null, even though it's not supposed to be".

A variable is not supposed to be null when it's a field on a class, and you have set the `--strictPropertyInitialization` setting in Typescript for example like this:

```
class MyClass {
 let x; // This throws an error "Property 'x' has no initializer
}

class MyClass {
 let x!; // No error
}
```

This comes in handy when you know that you will be setting this variable later on.